# linux vi editor special character gets converted into something else

Tags: linux, vim, vi

When I paste the below word in linux vi editor it gets changed:-

actual word :- Confirmación
changed word :- Confirmaciï¿½n

any idea why this is happening and how can i fix this?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading your file with ISO-Latin (ISO-8859-1) encoding:

```
:set fileencoding=ISO-8859-1
:e! ++enc=ISO-8859-1
:w!
```

Comment: I tried export LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1 before opening vi editor and it worked but not sure what it is all about.

Comment: encoding and charsets are compless matters, can't be explained briefly without the risk of causing more confusion. With your export you instructed vim (well, the shell to be more precise), to interpretate the chars according to the ISO-LATIN charset that includes your special char.